# Salesforce Lightning - Login Failure In Staging

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to login into my staging Salesforce lightning, by I get the following result:

> INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

I use the **'jsForce' library version 2**, with the right serverUrl, username and password+token combination.

Note that when I do **exactly the same for my production Salesforce environment - I succeed**.

Any suggestion to **why there's a difference between staging and production** - would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a Solution:** when logging to Salesforce using the jsForce libray, only the 'loginUrl' parameter works as expected (as opposed to 'serverUrl' for production).

Answer (score 1):

"exactly the same" to prod is probably bad idea, https://test.salesforce.com vs https://login.salesforce.com ;) And even if you have same password - the token could be different, password could have expired.

Do you see anything in the user's login history in setup? It's hard to guess these things. Do you get same result if you try SOAP API login or OAuth2? Or even plain old SF Data Loader?

- Maybe admin went to Setup -> My Domain and disabled logging in from generic address, forcing you to go https://mydomain--mysandboxname.my.salesforce.com/... ?
- Maybe admin enforced Single Sign-On on everybody and you can't use SF username & pass anymore.
- There might be restricted IP addresses or login hours set

Comment: Thanks! I've checked what you have suggested, but nothing works for now. Another important thing to note - is that the login attempt does not appear in the user's login attempts log in salesforce website. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: congrats on finding it and glad i could give you some pointers for investigation